# Running jnml results in Error: Could not find or load main class org.neuroml.JNeuroML

Tags: java, neural-network, neuroscience, biological-neural-network, neuroml

When running [jNeuroML](https://github.com/NeuroML/jNeuroML), I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.neuroml.JNeuroML
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error after reboot, the following makes sure it doesn't happen after a restart.

1. **Find the folder** where jNeuroML was extracted. There should be jnml executable in that folder and it runs from that folder without the above error. E.g. /Users/YourName/Downloads/jNeuroML-XYZ/
2. **Set the JNML_HOME** variable to the folder location, and **append** the folder location to the **PATH** environment variable.

Under *MacOS*, run these in Terminal (replace with your path)

```
export JNML_HOME=/Path/To/jnml/here/
export PATH=$PATH:$JNML_HOME
```

Under *Win7*:

> My Computer > Right Click > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Add New **JNML_HOME** variable, and Append to **PATH** variable

3. To **keep these after reboot**

Under *MacOS*, run this in terminal:

```
pico ~/.bash_profile
```

Paste the above two lines at the end of the file and save with `CTRL+X, Y, and ENTER`

Under *Win7*:

If you set them in Advanced System Settings, they will be preserved after reboot automatically.